# How can I match API URL in Kibana using regex?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

My log message is like this:

```
2020-04-06 07:25:34,728 150.249.199.64 3098 220 | "https://staging-app.mydomain.com/" "GET /api/test/123/ 200 0.7337"
```

And I want to match `/api/test/123/` using regex. Currently I'm using following query DSL in Kibana:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "regexp": {
            "message": "test"
          }
        },
        {
          "regexp": {
            "message": "api"
          }
        },
        {
          "regexp": {
            "message": "[0-9]{3}"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

But, this matches `2020`, `04`, `06`, `07`, `25`, `3098`, `220`, `/api/test/123/` and `200`

How can I modify the DSL query to just match `/api/test/123/` ?

Index pattern:
[image]

Comment: do you always need to match on the URLs ?

Comment: Yes, Just the URLs. like these `/api/test/123/`, `/api/test/1/`, `/api/test/12/`, etc

Comment: can you show your index mapping and ready to change it?

Comment: I've added index pattern in the question. And unfortunately I can't change it.

Comment: so basically you are using only one field `message` which is of type `string` ? and looks like you are using old version of ES, can you tell which one?

Comment: elasticsearch:6.4.1